# Begin Loading Video Immediately in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, safari, load

I've setup some HTML5  and everything is loading cross-browser.

I'm needed to perform the following event to pull the video dimensions:

```
$('#video').on('loadedmetadata',function(){
   var width=this.videoWidth, height=this.videoHeight;
   alert("meta has loaded!")
});
```

This alerts in all browsers, except Safari. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the loadedmetadata wasn't firing, but then realized that if I started playing the movie... it fired.

However, I need to retrieve the dimensions of the video before it's possible to play it. Is there any way to do this in Safari either by

- forcing Safari to load the meta data earlier like other browsers?
- use another method other than loadedmetadata?

UPDATE: Here's the exact code from the apple site:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Resizing Movies</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // set height and width to native values
        function naturalSize() {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.height = myVideo.videoHeight;
            myVideo.width = myVideo.videoWidth;
            alert("pulling dimensions!")
        }
        // register listener function on metadata load
        function myAddListener(){
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', naturalSize, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myAddListener()">
     <video src="http://homepage.mac.com/qt4web/myMovie.m4v" controls>
     </video>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the event listener does not fire until the video is invoked. Which means I'm unable to pull the dimensions until the video begins playing. This will alert in other browsers, but not in Safari because of (I'm guessing) how it's loading the video.

So, I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look here http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html

Comment: Thanks, I've read that page and am using the loadedmetadata listener exactly as it is on the page. But the problem is that event isn't fired on the ipad until the user begins playing the movie. I need to size a container before the video is shown.

Comment: You should update your question to specify A) that you're on an iPad and B) that your goal is to size the container. Apple has disallowed autoplaying videos on their iOS devices entirely in iOS 6.1, so that's a battle you just won't win. If you do figure it out, it'll be a loophole that they will fix in a future release. Note that you can't know the width and height of the video until the user initiates the playback, as referenced in the link from @ubercooluk

Comment: Exactly, which is kind of ridiculous. I knew autoplay was out of the question since Apple killed that on the ipad. Sorry for not mentioning ipad, it was in an earlier tag, but I swapped it out for video thinking it would be better. So, you're really saying that there isn't any way to retrieve the dimensions when the video is loaded (but playback hasn't initiated) on the ipad? All other browsers seem to handle it perfectly.